# K-harmonic means clustering with R

Tags: r, k-means

I recently read some interesting articles about "k-harmonic means" data clustering (KHM) algorithm as an improvement over the traditional k-means algorithm I am using. (in short, being less dependent on initial allocation of centers) 
Usually authors are mentioning matlab implementations of their algorithms. 
Not familiar with Matlab, and being more on the "user side", I would be interested to know if any R package uses this new idea? So far my searches have been unsuccessful.

Damien

Comment: seems unlikely.  `library("sos"); findFn("k-harmonic clustering")` finds nothing.

Comment: Thank you Ben, at least I learned about the library sos! Damien